# Creating wxSlider with range on Linux

Tags: python, linux, wxwidgets

I'm trying to create a slider with option for range selection using wxSlider in Python. It has an optional range parameter but the problem is:

SL_SELRANGE: Allows the user to select a range on the slider. Windows only.

And I'm using Linux.
I thought I might subclass wxSlider and make it work on Linux, or create a custom widget on my own. The problem is I'm not sure how to go about either option.
Any ideas/pointers/pointing me in the right direction would be appreciated.

I tried something like:

```
range_slider = wx.Slider(parent, wx.ID_ANY, 0, 0, 100, style=wx.SL_HORIZONTAL | wx.SL_LABELS | wx.SL_SELRANGE)
```

but the "SL_SELRANGE" does nothing on Linux (should provide two handles, to select range).

Comment: Add some code to demonstrate your problem

Comment: Check out the docs for the wxSlider cpp widget. [wxSlider Class Reference](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.0/classwx_slider.html)  
Note that these are upstream of wxPython and they state that this feature is windows only.   You will have to subclass in cpp to get over this hurdle.  Are you OK with that ?

Comment: That's just it.. I'm not really sure how to go about doing that in python..

Answer (score 2):

I'm aware this question is several years old, but even if it's too late to help you, it might help others, as I was going through the same problem recently.

#### Problem

Even in Windows, the `wx.SL_SELRANGE` style does not behave as one would expect, creating two independent "thumbs" or handles, which would allow the user to select a range (see [this similar question](https://discuss.wxpython.org/t/slider-with-the-range-selected-by-two-selectors/32819/5) and the [documentation](https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.Slider.html#styles-window-styles)). Instead, what it actually does is draw a static band in the trackbar, which does not interact with the single user-controlled thumb. To my knowledge it is not possible to customize the existing `wx.Slider` control to have two thumbs, since the control is native to the OS.

#### Solution

In an app I was building I needed to use a control that does what you wanted, but also could not find any good alternatives online. What I ended up doing is creating my own custom `RangeSlider` widget, which mimics the behavior and functionality of a regular `wx.Slider`, but with two thumbs:

[image: Range slider demo.]

Notice however that the `RangeSlider` class handles all the graphics rendering itself and I made it to mimic the Windows 10 look. Therefore the slider appearance will not match the style of a different OS, but it should still work in Linux or OSX. If necessary you could customize the appearance by changing the colors and shapes (all I do is draw rectangles and polygons).

There are some limitations to the widget, it doesn't currently support styles (no ticks or vertical sliders, for example) or validators, but I did implement the `wx.EVT_SLIDER` event, so other controls can be notified if the values change (this is what I use to dynamically update the text with the slider values, as the user moves the thumbs).

You can find below the code for a working example (it is also available in this [GitHub gist](https://gist.github.com/gabrieldp/e19611abead7f6617872d33866c568a3), where I may make improvements over time).

```
import wx


def fraction_to_value(fraction, min_value, max_value):
    return (max_value - min_value) * fraction + min_value


def value_to_fraction(value, min_value, max_value):
    return float(value - min_value) / (max_value - min_value)


class SliderThumb:
    def __init__(self, parent, value):
        self.parent = parent
        self.dragged = False
        self.mouse_over = False
        self.thumb_poly = ((0, 0), (0, 13), (5, 18), (10, 13), (10, 0))
        self.thumb_shadow_poly = ((0, 14), (4, 18), (6, 18), (10, 14))
        min_coords = [float('Inf'), float('Inf')]
        max_coords = [-float('Inf'), -float('Inf')]
        for pt in list(self.thumb_poly) + list(self.thumb_shadow_poly):
            for i_coord, coord in enumerate(pt):
                if coord > max_coords[i_coord]:
                    max_coords[i_coord] = coord
                if coord < min_coords[i_coord]:
                    min_coords[i_coord] = coord
        self.size = (max_coords[0] - min_coords[0],
                     max_coords[1] - min_coords[1])

        self.value = value
        self.normal_color = wx.Colour((0, 120, 215))
        self.normal_shadow_color = wx.Colour((120, 180, 228))
        self.dragged_color = wx.Colour((204, 204, 204))
        self.dragged_shadow_color = wx.Colour((222, 222, 222))
        self.mouse_over_color = wx.Colour((23, 23, 23))
        self.mouse_over_shadow_color = wx.Colour((132, 132, 132))

    def GetPosition(self):
        min_x = self.GetMin()
        max_x = self.GetMax()
        parent_size = self.parent.GetSize()
        min_value = self.parent.GetMin()
        max_value = self.parent.GetMax()
        fraction = value_to_fraction(self.value, min_value, max_value)
        pos = (fraction_to_value(fraction, min_x, max_x), parent_size[1] / 2 + 1)
        return pos

    def SetPosition(self, pos):
        pos_x = pos[0]
        # Limit movement by the position of the other thumb
        who_other, other_thumb = self.GetOtherThumb()
        other_pos = other_thumb.GetPosition()
        if who_other == 'low':
            pos_x = max(other_pos[0] + other_thumb.size[0]/2 + self.size[0]/2, pos_x)
        else:
            pos_x = min(other_pos[0] - other_thumb.size[0]/2 - self.size[0]/2, pos_x)
        # Limit movement by slider boundaries
        min_x = self.GetMin()
        max_x = self.GetMax()
        pos_x = min(max(pos_x, min_x), max_x)

        fraction = value_to_fraction(pos_x, min_x, max_x)
        self.value = fraction_to_value(fraction, self.parent.GetMin(), self.parent.GetMax())
        # Post event notifying that position changed
        self.PostEvent()

    def GetValue(self):
        return self.value

    def SetValue(self, value):
        self.value = value
        # Post event notifying that value changed
        self.PostEvent()

    def PostEvent(self):
        event = wx.PyCommandEvent(wx.EVT_SLIDER.typeId, self.parent.GetId())
        event.SetEventObject(self.parent)
        wx.PostEvent(self.parent.GetEventHandler(), event)

    def GetMin(self):
        min_x = self.parent.border_width + self.size[0] / 2
        return min_x

    def GetMax(self):
        parent_size = self.parent.GetSize()
        max_x = parent_size[0] - self.parent.border_width - self.size[0] / 2
        return max_x

    def IsMouseOver(self, mouse_pos):
        in_hitbox = True
        my_pos = self.GetPosition()
        for i_coord, mouse_coord in enumerate(mouse_pos):
            boundary_low = my_pos[i_coord] - self.size[i_coord] / 2
            boundary_high = my_pos[i_coord] + self.size[i_coord] / 2
            in_hitbox = in_hitbox and (boundary_low <= mouse_coord <= boundary_high)
        return in_hitbox

    def GetOtherThumb(self):
        if self.parent.thumbs['low'] != self:
            return 'low', self.parent.thumbs['low']
        else:
            return 'high', self.parent.thumbs['high']

    def OnPaint(self, dc):
        if self.dragged or not self.parent.IsEnabled():
            thumb_color = self.dragged_color
            thumb_shadow_color = self.dragged_shadow_color
        elif self.mouse_over:
            thumb_color = self.mouse_over_color
            thumb_shadow_color = self.mouse_over_shadow_color
        else:
            thumb_color = self.normal_color
            thumb_shadow_color = self.normal_shadow_color
        my_pos = self.GetPosition()

        # Draw thumb shadow (or anti-aliasing effect)
        dc.SetBrush(wx.Brush(thumb_shadow_color, style=wx.BRUSHSTYLE_SOLID))
        dc.SetPen(wx.Pen(thumb_shadow_color, width=1, style=wx.PENSTYLE_SOLID))
        dc.DrawPolygon(points=self.thumb_shadow_poly,
                       xoffset=my_pos[0] - self.size[0]/2,
                       yoffset=my_pos[1] - self.size[1]/2)
        # Draw thumb itself
        dc.SetBrush(wx.Brush(thumb_color, style=wx.BRUSHSTYLE_SOLID))
        dc.SetPen(wx.Pen(thumb_color, width=1, style=wx.PENSTYLE_SOLID))
        dc.DrawPolygon(points=self.thumb_poly,
                       xoffset=my_pos[0] - self.size[0] / 2,
                       yoffset=my_pos[1] - self.size[1] / 2)


class RangeSlider(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent, id=wx.ID_ANY, lowValue=None, highValue=None, minValue=0, maxValue=100,
                 pos=wx.DefaultPosition, size=wx.DefaultSize, style=wx.SL_HORIZONTAL, validator=wx.DefaultValidator,
                 name='rangeSlider'):
        if style != wx.SL_HORIZONTAL:
            raise NotImplementedError('Styles not implemented')
        if validator != wx.DefaultValidator:
            raise NotImplementedError('Validator not implemented')
        super().__init__(parent=parent, id=id, pos=pos, size=size, name=name)
        self.SetMinSize(size=(max(50, size[0]), max(26, size[1])))
        if minValue > maxValue:
            minValue, maxValue = maxValue, minValue
        self.min_value = minValue
        self.max_value = maxValue
        if lowValue is None:
            lowValue = self.min_value
        if highValue is None:
            highValue = self.max_value
        if lowValue > highValue:
            lowValue, highValue = highValue, lowValue
        lowValue = max(lowValue, self.min_value)
        highValue = min(highValue, self.max_value)

        self.border_width = 8

        self.thumbs = {
            'low': SliderThumb(parent=self, value=lowValue),
            'high': SliderThumb(parent=self, value=highValue)
        }
        self.thumb_width = self.thumbs['low'].size[0]

        # Aesthetic definitions
        self.slider_background_color = wx.Colour((231, 234, 234))
        self.slider_outline_color = wx.Colour((214, 214, 214))
        self.selected_range_color = wx.Colour((0, 120, 215))
        self.selected_range_outline_color = wx.Colour((0, 120, 215))

        # Bind events
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_DOWN, self.OnMouseDown)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_UP, self.OnMouseUp)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MOTION, self.OnMouseMotion)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MOUSE_CAPTURE_LOST, self.OnMouseLost)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_ENTER_WINDOW, self.OnMouseEnter)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_LEAVE_WINDOW, self.OnMouseLeave)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_PAINT, self.OnPaint)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_ERASE_BACKGROUND, self.OnEraseBackground)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_SIZE, self.OnResize)

    def Enable(self, enable=True):
        super().Enable(enable)
        self.Refresh()

    def Disable(self):
        super().Disable()
        self.Refresh()

    def SetValueFromMousePosition(self, click_pos):
        for thumb in self.thumbs.values():
            if thumb.dragged:
                thumb.SetPosition(click_pos)

    def OnMouseDown(self, evt):
        if not self.IsEnabled():
            return
        click_pos = evt.GetPosition()
        for thumb in self.thumbs.values():
            if thumb.IsMouseOver(click_pos):
                thumb.dragged = True
                thumb.mouse_over = False
                break
        self.SetValueFromMousePosition(click_pos)
        self.CaptureMouse()
        self.Refresh()

    def OnMouseUp(self, evt):
        if not self.IsEnabled():
            return
        self.SetValueFromMousePosition(evt.GetPosition())
        for thumb in self.thumbs.values():
            thumb.dragged = False
        if self.HasCapture():
            self.ReleaseMouse()
        self.Refresh()

    def OnMouseLost(self, evt):
        for thumb in self.thumbs.values():
            thumb.dragged = False
            thumb.mouse_over = False
        self.Refresh()

    def OnMouseMotion(self, evt):
        if not self.IsEnabled():
            return
        refresh_needed = False
        mouse_pos = evt.GetPosition()
        if evt.Dragging() and evt.LeftIsDown():
            self.SetValueFromMousePosition(mouse_pos)
            refresh_needed = True
        else:
            for thumb in self.thumbs.values():
                old_mouse_over = thumb.mouse_over
                thumb.mouse_over = thumb.IsMouseOver(mouse_pos)
                if old_mouse_over != thumb.mouse_over:
                    refresh_needed = True
        if refresh_needed:
            self.Refresh()

    def OnMouseEnter(self, evt):
        if not self.IsEnabled():
            return
        mouse_pos = evt.GetPosition()
        for thumb in self.thumbs.values():
            if thumb.IsMouseOver(mouse_pos):
                thumb.mouse_over = True
                self.Refresh()
                break

    def OnMouseLeave(self, evt):
        if not self.IsEnabled():
            return
        for thumb in self.thumbs.values():
            thumb.mouse_over = False
        self.Refresh()

    def OnResize(self, evt):
        self.Refresh()

    def OnPaint(self, evt):
        w, h = self.GetSize()
        # BufferedPaintDC should reduce flickering
        dc = wx.BufferedPaintDC(self)
        background_brush = wx.Brush(self.GetBackgroundColour(), wx.SOLID)
        dc.SetBackground(background_brush)
        dc.Clear()
        # Draw slider
        track_height = 12
        dc.SetPen(wx.Pen(self.slider_outline_color, width=1, style=wx.PENSTYLE_SOLID))
        dc.SetBrush(wx.Brush(self.slider_background_color, style=wx.BRUSHSTYLE_SOLID))
        dc.DrawRectangle(self.border_width, h/2 - track_height/2, w - 2 * self.border_width, track_height)
        # Draw selected range
        if self.IsEnabled():
            dc.SetPen(wx.Pen(self.selected_range_outline_color, width=1, style=wx.PENSTYLE_SOLID))
            dc.SetBrush(wx.Brush(self.selected_range_color, style=wx.BRUSHSTYLE_SOLID))
        else:
            dc.SetPen(wx.Pen(self.slider_outline_color, width=1, style=wx.PENSTYLE_SOLID))
            dc.SetBrush(wx.Brush(self.slider_outline_color, style=wx.BRUSHSTYLE_SOLID))
        low_pos = self.thumbs['low'].GetPosition()[0]
        high_pos = self.thumbs['high'].GetPosition()[0]
        dc.DrawRectangle(low_pos, h / 2 - track_height / 4, high_pos - low_pos, track_height / 2)
        # Draw thumbs
        for thumb in self.thumbs.values():
            thumb.OnPaint(dc)
        evt.Skip()

    def OnEraseBackground(self, evt):
        # This should reduce flickering
        pass

    def GetValues(self):
        return self.thumbs['low'].value, self.thumbs['high'].value

    def SetValues(self, lowValue, highValue):
        if lowValue > highValue:
            lowValue, highValue = highValue, lowValue
        lowValue = max(lowValue, self.min_value)
        highValue = min(highValue, self.max_value)
        self.thumbs['low'].SetValue(lowValue)
        self.thumbs['high'].SetValue(highValue)
        self.Refresh()

    def GetMax(self):
        return self.max_value

    def GetMin(self):
        return self.min_value

    def SetMax(self, maxValue):
        if maxValue < self.min_value:
            maxValue = self.min_value
        _, old_high = self.GetValues()
        if old_high > maxValue:
            self.thumbs['high'].SetValue(maxValue)
        self.max_value = maxValue
        self.Refresh()

    def SetMin(self, minValue):
        if minValue > self.max_value:
            minValue = self.max_value
        old_low, _ = self.GetValues()
        if old_low < minValue:
            self.thumbs['low'].SetValue(minValue)
        self.min_value = minValue
        self.Refresh()


class TestFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, -1, 'Range Slider Demo', size=(300, 100))
        panel = wx.Panel(self)
        b = 6
        vbox = wx.BoxSizer(orient=wx.VERTICAL)
        vbox.Add(wx.StaticText(parent=panel, label='Custom Range Slider:'), flag=wx.ALIGN_LEFT | wx.ALL, border=b)
        self.rangeslider = RangeSlider(parent=panel, lowValue=20, highValue=80, minValue=0, maxValue=100,
                                       size=(300, 26))
        self.rangeslider.Bind(wx.EVT_SLIDER, self.rangeslider_changed)
        vbox.Add(self.rangeslider, proportion=1, flag=wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, border=b)
        self.rangeslider_static = wx.StaticText(panel)
        vbox.Add(self.rangeslider_static, flag=wx.ALIGN_LEFT | wx.ALL, border=b)
        vbox.Add(wx.StaticText(parent=panel, label='Regular Slider with wx.SL_SELRANGE style:'),
                 flag=wx.ALIGN_LEFT | wx.ALL, border=b)
        self.slider = wx.Slider(parent=panel, style=wx.SL_SELRANGE)
        self.slider.SetSelection(20, 40)
        self.slider.Bind(wx.EVT_SLIDER, self.slider_changed)
        vbox.Add(self.slider, proportion=1, flag=wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, border=b)
        self.slider_static = wx.StaticText(panel)
        vbox.Add(self.slider_static, flag=wx.ALIGN_LEFT | wx.ALL, border=b)
        self.button_toggle = wx.Button(parent=panel, label='Disable')
        self.button_toggle.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.toggle_slider_enable)
        vbox.Add(self.button_toggle, flag=wx.ALIGN_CENTER | wx.ALL, border=b)
        panel.SetSizerAndFit(vbox)
        box = wx.BoxSizer()
        box.Add(panel, proportion=1, flag=wx.EXPAND)
        self.SetSizerAndFit(box)

    def slider_changed(self, evt):
        obj = evt.GetEventObject()
        val = obj.GetValue()
        self.slider_static.SetLabel('Value: {}'.format(val))

    def rangeslider_changed(self, evt):
        obj = evt.GetEventObject()
        lv, hv = obj.GetValues()
        self.rangeslider_static.SetLabel('Low value: {:.0f}, High value: {:.0f}'.format(lv, hv))

    def toggle_slider_enable(self, evt):
        if self.button_toggle.GetLabel() == 'Disable':
            self.slider.Enable(False)
            self.rangeslider.Enable(False)
            self.button_toggle.SetLabel('Enable')
        else:
            self.slider.Enable(True)
            self.rangeslider.Enable(True)
            self.button_toggle.SetLabel('Disable')


def main():
    app = wx.App()
    TestFrame().Show()
    app.MainLoop()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

You could have two sliders; one that will push the other so it remains lower, and one will remain higher?

I know it isn't the same thing, sorry, but it is an option.
So when ever self.minSlider is moved, you bind wx.EVT_SCROLL with a function that will do something like:

```
self.minSlider.Bind(wx.EVT_SCROLL, self.respondSliderChange())

def respondSliderChange(self):
    if self.minSlider.GetValue() >= self.maxSlider.GetValue():
        self.maxSlider.SetValue(self.minSlider.GetValue()+1)
```

and vice-versa for the maxSlider.

Besides that, you can look into creating a custom widget [here](http://zetcode.com/gui/wxwidgets/customwidgets/).

Answer (score 0):

Something related has been described [here](http://wxpython-users.1045709.n5.nabble.com/Creating-a-custom-slider-td2342597.html).

In a nutshell the idea is to draw a box, and colour part of it to represent your range. From the left where your user left-click, and from the right where your user right-click.

Instead of a box and colouring, you could draw some markers on a line:

```
--------[-----------]--
```

Comment: I already saw that, thanks. This would be my last resort..
The idea was to use the builtin wxSlider with RANGE option on Linux, meaning tweak it somehow to work, I don't want to have to draw the whole thing myself and do a lot of extra work that can be avoided basically.